# Neural Network Mini Batch Gradient Descent

Tags: machine-learning, neural-network, gradient-descent

I am working with a multi-layer neural network. I intend to do mini-batch gradient descent. Suppose I have mini-batches of 100 over 1 million data points. I don't understand the part where I have to update the weights of the whole network. When I do a forward pass over these 100 samples, I sum all the errors over these 100 samples. What else do I do apart from this? Do I have to compute the hidden layer errors side by side too? When will they be computed?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

## Batch learning in neural networks

You have to calculate the weight deltas for each neuron in all of the layers in you network, for each data instance in your (chosen) dataset. This is the same procedure as always in backpropagation.

Since you wish to use batch learning, you will delay the weight update step. Instead you should store these deltas and add up the deltas from the different instances in your batch after the batch has completed. Then use these newly manipulated deltas to update the weights in your network.

[image]

Comment: Can I just store all the errors and compute the cumulated weight deltas at the end? Will it be the same?

Comment: Yes, that would be computationally better!

Comment: I thought that the size of the batch is a hyperparameter that needs tuning somehow?

Comment: The more samples included in a batch, the more "smoothed" will the update delta become. This implies that the weights will more likely avoid local optima, at the cost of slower convergence. Using batch learning tend to speed up the training proceedure. For instance, fitting a network to MNIST is quicker using batch learning.